# SQLite Data isn't showing in recycleview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I've been trying to show my sqlite data in android app using recycleview in fragments.But cardview isn't showing any data though logcat is showing that I'm getting data from the table.

This is my memberActivity where I have called the recycleview and created a adapter class 
MemberActivity.java:

```
package com.aust.austpc.austpcbeta6.database;

import ...
public class MemberActivity extends Fragment {
     RecyclerView recyclerView;
     ArrayList<MemberDesc> listItems;
     MemAdapter adapter = null;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_member,container,false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.member_activity);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        listItems=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(v.getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= databaseHandler.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = databaseHandler.getAllData();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.i(TAG, cursor.getColumnName(0));
        do{
            MemberDesc memberDesc=new MemberDesc();
            listItems.add(memberDesc);
            Log.i(TAG, "SHOWING");

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        databaseHandler.close();
        adapter=new MemAdapter(listItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Member");
    }
    }


    class MemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MemAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private ArrayList<MemberDesc> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public MemAdapter(ArrayList<MemberDesc> listItems) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }


    @Override
    public MemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.member_row,parent,false);
        return new MemAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MemberDesc memberDesc=listItems.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(memberDesc.getName());
        holder.textViewRoll.setText(memberDesc.getRoll());
        holder.textViewPhone.setText(memberDesc.getPhone());
        holder.textViewYear.setText(memberDesc.getYear());
        holder.textViewSem.setText(memberDesc.getSem());
        Log.i(TAG, holder.textViewName.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //int i=listItems.size();
        //Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(i));
        return listItems.size();

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewRoll;
        public TextView textViewPhone;
        public TextView textViewYear;
        public TextView textViewSem;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.memName);
            textViewRoll=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.memRoll);
            textViewPhone=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.memPhone);
            textViewYear=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.memYear);
            textViewSem=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.memSem);
        }
    }
}
```

member_row.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/memName" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/memRoll"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/memPhone"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/memYear"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/memSem"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

MemberDesc.java:

```
package com.aust.austpc.austpcbeta6.database;

/**
 * Created by USER on 2/3/2018.
 */

public class MemberDesc {
    private String name, roll, phone, year, sem;

    public MemberDesc(String name, String roll, String phone, String year, String sem) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roll = roll;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.year = year;
        this.sem = sem;
    }
    public MemberDesc()
    {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public String getSem() {
        return sem;
    }

}
```

DatabaseHandler.java:

```
package com.aust.austpc.austpcbeta6.database;

import ...
/**
 * Created by USER on 2/3/2018.
 */

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{



    public static final String Database_Name="MEMBER.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="MEMBER_TABLE";
    public static final String KEY_ID="ID";
    public static final String KEY_NAME ="NAME";
    public static final String KEY_ROLL="ROLL";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT="CONTACT";
    public static final String KEY_YEAR="YEAR";
    public static final String KEY_SEMESTER="SEMESTER";





    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context,Database_Name,null,1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,ROLL TEXT,CONTACT TEXT,YEAR TEXT,SEMESTER TEXT)");
        Log.i(TAG, "Datbase CREATED");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);



    }
    public boolean insertData(String NAME,String  ROLL, String CONTACT, String YEAR, String SEMESTER)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_NAME,NAME);
        contentValues.put(KEY_ROLL,ROLL);
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTACT,CONTACT);
        contentValues.put(KEY_YEAR,YEAR);
        contentValues.put(KEY_SEMESTER,SEMESTER);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }
    public Cursor getAllData(){
        SQLiteDatabase  db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " +TABLE_NAME, null);
        return cursor;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any data in your database?

Comment: I didn't understand your answer.Can you explain me further in details.

Comment: so why do you want to make your life harder? why dont you want to use a simple solution? as i said you have to override **only two methods**, nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the data as parameters to the DATA OBJECT Class Constructor **MemberDesc()**

try this .

```
do{
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME");
            String roll = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ROLL");
            String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CONTACT");
            String year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("YEAR");
            String sem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SEMESTER");
            MemberDesc memberDesc=new MemberDesc(name,roll,phone,year sem);
            listItems.add(memberDesc);
            Log.i(TAG, "SHOWING");

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Hope this may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Create a Method like this

```
    public ArrayList<CartData> getAllData(){
    ArrayList<CartData> d = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String select = "SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            CartData dta = new CartData(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getBlob(5));
            d.add(dta);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return d;
}
```

now add this in getAllData() method in your adapter

```
finalCartAdapter = new FinalCartAdapter(FinalOrderActivity.this, sqLiteHandler.getAllData());
    finalCartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    finalItems.setAdapter(finalCartAdapter);
```

but lastly u require a CartData.class

```
public class CartData {

String title;
String printname;
String mrp;
String qty;
byte[] image;

public CartData(String title, String printname, String mrp, String qty,byte[] image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.printname = printname;
    this.mrp = mrp;
    this.qty = qty;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getPrintname() {
    return printname;
}

public void setPrintname(String printname) {
    this.printname = printname;
}

public String getMrp() {
    return mrp;
}

public void setMrp(String mrp) {
    this.mrp = mrp;
}

public String getQty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setQty(String qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}

public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

U got a readymade code by the way. just change cartData items to the fields mapped in your Sqlite.